# Activate sheet in workbook with name that matches the Day of current date

Tags: excel, vba

first post!

So I have a macro that updates the data in a workbook on 5 different sheets. Each sheet is named after a day of the week, Monday - Friday.

I would like to have the macro activate whichever sheet matches the current calendar day upon completion but cannot seem to figure out the code.

For example, if I run the update code on a Wednesday I would like the sheet titled "Wednesday" to be activated as the final step.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, apologies if I have missed anything!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
Dim tDay as String
tDay = Format(Date,"dddd")
Thisworkbook.Sheets(tDay).Activate
```

Comment: This got me close however I had to edit it as follows for complete success.

Dim tDay As String
tDay = Format(Date, "dddd")
Sheets(tDay).Select

Answer (score 0):

OK, using Jordan's suggestion I was able to solve my problem and the resulting code is as follows.

```
 Dim tDay As String<br>
 tDay = Format(Date, "dddd")<br>
 Sheets(tDay).Select
```

Thanks so much!!!